# Building FANN Python bindings under Windows

Tags: python, windows, fann

I tried to compile the python bindings (pyfann) for FANN via *python setup.py install*. With an installed Visual Studio 2010 and SWIGWIN I get several errors.

Has anyone a precompiled version of the python bindings for Python 2.7 under Windows 7 and/or 8? I also tried that one [pyfann under windows](http://blog.csdn.net/conceptnn/article/details/9191735), but the build of _libfann.pyd aborted.

Answer (score 2):

I have compiled fann for python 2.7.
 
You can download it from here: https://github.com/jacekm-git/pyfann_python2.7_windows

### Compilation steps :

#### 1. Swig installation:

- download: sourceforge.net/projects/swig/files/swigwin/
- extract files to C:\swigwin\
- edit system path variable

  - rigth click MyComputer -> properties
  - "advanced" tab -> "Environment Variables"
  - edit "Path" variable -> add ";C:\swigwin\;C:\python27\;C:\python27\Scripts\" on the end of the line.

#### 2. Microsoft Visual C++ Studio 2008 Express:

- download and install : go.microsoft.com/?linkid=7729279

#### 3. Fann 2.1

- download: http://sourceforge.net/projects/fann/files/fann/2.1.0beta/fann-2.1.0beta.zip/download
- extract files to : C:\fann\

#### 4. Compile fanndoubled.dll

- open C:\fann\MicrosoftWindowsDll\windll.vcproj in Visual C++ Studio 2008
- Build -> Build windll
- copy files fanndoubled.dll, fanndoubled.lib to C:\fann\python\pyfann

#### 5. Swig

- open command prompt

```
    cd c:\fann\python\pyfann\
    swig -c++ -python pyfann.i
```

- open in Visual C++ Studio 2008 C:\fann\python\pyfann.wrap.cxx

  - find line( ctrl+f) : SWIGINTERN PyObject     *_wrap_training_data_parent_create_train_from_callback

```
    SWIGINTERN PyObject *_wrap_training_data_parent_create_train_from_callback(PyObject*SWIGUNUSEDPARM(self), PyObject *args) {
      PyObject *resultobj = 0;
      FANN::training_data *arg1 = (FANN::training_data *) 0 ;
      unsigned int arg2 ;
      unsigned int arg3 ;
      unsigned int arg4 ;
      void (*arg5)(unsigned int,unsigned int,unsigned int,fann_type *,fann_type *) = (void (*)(unsigned int,unsigned int,unsigned int,fann_type *,fann_type *)) 0 ;
      // .... rest of file ...
```

change to:

```
    typedef void (__stdcall *arg5_fn)(unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int, fann_type*, fann_type*); // added line 
    SWIGINTERN PyObject *_wrap_training_data_parent_create_train_from_callback(PyObject *SWIGUNUSEDPARM(self), PyObject *args) {
      PyObject *resultobj = 0;
      FANN::training_data *arg1 = (FANN::training_data *) 0 ;
      unsigned int arg2 ;
      unsigned int arg3 ;
      unsigned int arg4 ;
      /* void (*arg5)(unsigned int,unsigned int,unsigned int,fann_type *,fann_type *) = (void (*)(unsigned int,unsigned int,unsigned int,fann_type *,fann_type *)) 0 ;*/
      arg5_fn arg5= (arg5_fn)NULL; // added line
      // ....
```

#### 6. setup.py

- open in editor C:\fann\python\pyfann\setup.py
- find and comment lines:

```
    # swig_cmd = 'swig -c++ -python pyfann/pyfann.i'
    # print 'Running SWIG before:', swig_cmd
    # os.system(swig_cmd)
```

- change setup lines to:

```
    ext_modules=[Extension('pyfann._libfann',['pyfann/pyfann_wrap.cxx'], 
                            include_dirs=['../src/include'], 
                            # extra_objects=['../src/doublefann.o'], 
                            libraries = ['pyfann/fanndoubled'],
                            define_macros=[("SWIG_COMPILE",None)]
                                ),
```

#### 7. installation

```
    cd C:\fann\python\
    python setup.py install
    copy C:\fann\python\pyfann\fanndoubled.dll C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\pyfann\
```